# Add a hyperlink to the Discussion area of a WorkItem

Tags: tfs

I want to add a link to the url of a specific wiki page in a tfs project in the discussion area of a workitem.

I just get text:
http://tfs.xxxx.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project%2...  as text.

I've tried using some markdown syntax that doesn't seem to work. Then I just get markdown with the url text.

Not possible?

Comment: I should add that I can add a link to a wiki page using the Link function up by add an attachment. However, short of seeing that there are multiple links noted in the count there is nothing to draw the user to that link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, Markdown is not supported yet in Discussions for now, and there's already a **[user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32339500-add-markdown-support-in-discussions)** submitted to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

For now we can only use **#** to link a work item, **!** to link a pull request or **@** to mention a person.

However it will keep the links in discussion (comment) area if you copy the texts which have inserted hyperlinks for them.

So **as a workaround,** you could add the hyperlink to text first (e.g. from **web-page** or MS **WORD** ), then copy the text into Discussion (comment), save the work item.

e.g:

[Test Wiki page](http://tfs2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ScrumProject/ScrumProject%20Team/_wiki/wikis/ScrumProject.wiki?wikiVersion=GBwikiMaster&pagePath=%2FTest%200627) , then copy texts as comment in discussion area.

[image]

Comment: Took me a minute to understand your answer but it is a very viable workaround. Thx!